# git commit --amend does not commit changes

Tags: git

Any time I make changes locally and do either `git commit --amend`, then `:x` to save and close out of vim OR even just `git commit --amend --no-edit` nothing happens. None of the local changes are committed or staged. I'm completely stumped how it's even possible. Other `rebase`ing activity works as normal with the editor.

Here's a full working repro:

```
amendwtf|master ⇒ ls
file
amendwtf|master ⇒ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
amendwtf|master ⇒ echo 'a change appears' > file
amendwtf|master⚡ ⇒ git status
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   file

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
amendwtf|master⚡ ⇒ git commit --amend --no-edit
[master 3b577b8] initial commit
 Date: Thu Mar 14 09:49:08 2019 -0400
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 file
amendwtf|master⚡ ⇒ git status
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   file

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
amendwtf|master⚡ ⇒
```

git and vim versions:

```
amendwtf|master⚡ ⇒ git --version
git version 2.21.0
amendwtf|master⚡ ⇒ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Nov 29 2017 18:37:46)
Included patches: 1-503, 505-680, 682-1283
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't staged anything for commit (using `git add file`), and you didn't put any filenames on the commit commandline, therefore `git commit --amend` will only edit the commit message, the commit date/time, and possibly other things listed on the command-line (none in your case). If you want to commit changes to a file, add the file first, or specify it on the commit commandline.

Answer (score 3):

I was forgetting a `-a`. What I wanted was `git commit -a --amend --no-edit`.

Comment: I recommend *not* using `-a`. Instead, run `git add -u` first—that's what `git commit -a` does, but now you can run `git status` and be sure that the output reflects what you want to happen during your next `git commit`, whether that's with `--amend` or without. (Though of course once you're familiar with `git add -u`, and are sure it's going to do what you want, *then* `git commit -a` is fine. I still use `-u` myself though!)